Cannot configure Basic authentication in nginx for an Android client
I am trying to set up an nginx web server on a Raspberry Pi with access from Android. Android v.14 insists on Basic authentication but I cannot get it to work.
My home network includes a CalDAV calendar hosted on Baïkal with nginx on a Raspberry Pi 3B running PiOS. Everything is the latest version. It is supposed to allow me to share a calendar between my desktop (Linux and Thunderbird) and an Android phone running OneCalendar. The devices should sync automatically when they are both connected on my home network. It used to work with plain http, until an Android update.
All three devices have IP addresses in the range 192.168.1.* . I am not too concerned about security, since everything is behind my firewall, so everything below is as lax as possible, at least until it works.
I have set up Basic authentication, according to the nginx documentation:  https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/
sudo apt install apache2-utils
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/ssl/.htpasswd myuser
sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite

That all appeared to work. Here are the new lines in the location section of my site file:
auth_basic "Baikal";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/ssl/.htpasswd;
satisfy any;
allow 192.168.1.0/24;
deny all;

I can find no sign of ssl configuration in the nginx files.
The strange thing is that Thunderbird ‘just works’ but Android fails, saying “Digest authentication not supported, please try to enable Basic authentication on your server.” nginx reports a "401 Unauthorized" error to the phone. These lines appear in the nginx error log:
http fastcgi header: "Status: 401 Unauthorized"
http fastcgi header: "WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="BaikalDAV",qop="auth",nonce="66ddb6608ccb4",opaque="d66d5f0524036afcb61420e358f990ce""
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="BaikalDAV",qop="auth",nonce="66ddb6608ccb4",opaque="d66d5f0524036afcb61420e358f990ce"

I have checked several times that the two clients use the same URL (http://192.168.1.11:9999/cal.php/calendars/myuser/default), user name and password. Any help in overcoming these problems would be appreciated.

These WWW-Authenticate headers aren't being sent by Nginx – they're sent by the webapp itself. You need to change dav_auth_type in Baïkal's config.yaml.

That's it! The authorization type should be changed through the Baikal web admin site, System Settings page.
